# What's wrong with my code....?

Tags: c

this is my code i want to print the events of p1 and p2,...help.. is there any problem in array declaration....i a m not getting the expected result...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
    int main(){
int p1[8],p2[8];
int e,i,m1,m2;
printf("no of events in p1 and p2");
scanf("%d",&e);
printf("event of p1 which will send message:");
scanf("%d",&m1);
printf("event of p2 which will receive message:");
scanf("%d",&m2);
p1[1]=1;
p2[1]=1;
for(i=2;i<=e;i++)
  {
      if(i!=m2)
      {
          p1[i]=p1[i-1]+1;
          p2[i]=p2[i-1]+1;
      }
      else{
       p2[i]=p1[m1]+1;
      }
  }
  printf("Event of p1 are");
  for(i=1;i<e;i++)
     {
         printf("%d",p1[i]);
     }
  printf("Event of p2 are");

  for(i=1;i<e;i++)
     {
         printf("%d",p2[i]);
     }
return 0;
}
```

...help.. is there any problem in array declaration....my code is not running properly...

Comment: you use p[1] , but you never define the `p`array , only `p1`, `p2` etc...

Comment: @Noob_coder Next time be more precise about what you mean with "my code is not running properly" (it does not compile, it behaves like this instead of the expected behavior, etc.)

Comment: Well, what is wrong with it? You didn't tell us. You did not tell us what it is meant to do. You did not tell us what it actually does. You supplied bogus code. Is it really that hard to paste your actual program into the question? Obviously after you have cut it down to the bare minimum.

Comment: sorry for everything ...............i just want to show the main problem where i am stucked......and that's why i shorted the code...i want my code to print the event of process p1 and p2 using logical clock.........

Answer (score 1):

You do not have anything called `p` in your code - do this:

```
p1[1]=1;
p2[1]=1;
```

or

```
p1[1]=1;
p1[2]=1;
```

Also, i am not sure if you have initialized `e`.

Comment: yes it worked but there is a problem when i want to print ..for(i=1;i<e;i++)
     {
         printf("%d",p1[i]);
     } i am not getting the proper value

Comment: Have you initialized `e`?

Answer (score 0):

you did not define a p array. you defined p1 and p2 as arrays
may be you mean

```
p1[1]=1;
p2[1]=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

your assignment is wrong.

```
p[1]=1;//prob
p[2]=1;//prob
```

should be

```
p1[1]=1;
p2[1]=1;
```

in my opinion.